# Prevent the browser from rendering a CSS change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I have the following block of code that I need to complete as quickly as possible:

```
//someSpans is an array of spans, with each span containing two child spans inside of it
$.each( someSpans, function (i, span) {
    //Get the span widths, then add them to the style to make them permanent
    var aSpan = span.children[0];
    var bSpan = span.children[1];
    span.style.width = (aSpan.offsetWidth + bSpan.offsetWidth) + 'px';
    aSpan.style.width = aSpan.offsetWidth + 'px';
    bSpan.style.width = bSpan.offsetWidth + 'px';
});
```

If someSpans is an array that contains 1000 objects, this loop presented above will cause 3000 browser redraws, even though nothing on screen is actually changing, since the new "width" attributes in the style match the existing "auto" width.  Is there a way to prevent the browser from redrawing the CSS until the loop is finished?  I feel like this will greatly reduce the time it takes for the loop to complete.

I feel like [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) might be the key to doing what I'm looking for, but maybe I'm off base.

Comment: It might be worth asking why you are doing this in the first place?

Comment: Have you read up on layout thrashing? http://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/

http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/

Comment: @Mathletics I am placing every individual word in a contenteditable div into its own span in a hidden proxy div.  This allows me to detect which word/character a user's mouse is hovering over at any given moment.  Obviously as soon as the user changes the content, the whole block of text needs to be respanned to match the changes.  That's why speed is so important.

Comment: @AndrewWalters no I have not, but this sounds like more or less exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If performance is so important why you use jQuery? with pure javascript it would be much faster, and if you want to prevent browser rendering DOM Elements before loop finished you can put it in [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and then append elements where they should be. Also look at [Document.createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker)

Comment: @Givi, I just tried it without the jquery.each (used a for loop instead), and it made no discernible difference.  As for the docFragment, does using that essentially create an unrendered document object, which can then be appended to the existing doc when its ready?

Comment: Yes, look at [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/d9b4m/)

Comment: or with setTimeout [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/d9b4m/3/)

Comment: @Givi: just wanted to let you know that I went with an alternate method utilizing DocumentFragments to greatly reduce the speed of the operation.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

While the comments of *why* make a great point, here's a little better answer.

Part of your problem here is the alternating reads/writes from the style. Namely, setting `span.style.width` has now made `aSpan.offsetWidth` "dirty" and the CSS must be rendered. However, consider this:

```
var aWidth = aSpan.offsetWidth;
var bWidth = bSpan.offsetWidth;
span.style.width = (aWidth + bWidth) + 'px';
aSpan.style.width = aWidth + 'px';
bSpan.style.width = bWidth + 'px';
```

The rendering is now cut down to once per loop. More specifically, it's in reading `offsetWidth` on the *next* iteration that causes the render.

**Exercise:** While it can make code a little more obtuse, sometimes unnecessarily so, I have sometimes written code like this to loop twice. The first time collects the operations into an array, and the second loop is able to combine all the "setting" operations without accessing any layout values.

MSDN has some great [documents on JavaScript performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465194.aspx) with the most applicable here being ["Managing layout efficiently"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781220.aspx)